# Prevent parent from rerendering while setting state from children in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this simple chat app, containing a parent component `Chat`, inside it I loop through messages and create a `ChatLine` component for each message. I also have a small menu in the parent component component because I don't need to create a menu for each child, and I have a `setOpenMenu` to toggle it, I'm passing the `line`, `openMenu` & `setOpenMenu` as props to the child `ChatLine`.

The entire code is also available in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-http-7tt3l) & [Netlify](https://csb-7tt3l.netlify.app/)

Here is the code : (Chat.js)

```
import { useState } from "react";
import ChatLine from "./ChatLine";

const Chat = () => {
  const [openMenu, setOpenMenu] = useState(null);
  const [chatLines, setChatLines] = useState([
    { id: 1, message: "Hello" },
    { id: 2, message: "Hi" },
    { id: 3, message: "Bye" },
  ]);

  return (
    <div>
      {openMenu && (
        <div
          style={{
            width: "100px",
            height: "100px",
            backgroundColor: "#000",
            borderRadius: "5px",
            position: "absolute",
            left: "200px",
          }}
        >
          <div>EDIT</div>
          <div>DELETE</div>
          <div>MORE...</div>
        </div>
      )}
      <p>MESSAGES :</p>
      {chatLines.map((line) => (
        <ChatLine
          key={line.id}
          line={line}
          setOpenMenu={setOpenMenu}
          openMenu={openMenu}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

& ChatLine.js :

```
const ChatLine = ({ line, setOpenMenu, openMenu }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>{line.id}: </span>
      <span>{line.message}</span>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setOpenMenu(!openMenu || openMenu !== line.id ? line.id : null);
        }}
      >
        Options
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChatLine;
```

So the problem is that the parent component `Chat.js` rerenders everytime `ChatLine` toggles the menu when I click in the `Options` button.

Is there a way to prevent the parent from rerendering when changing the menu's state while keeping the menu separate from `ChatLine` so we don't loop through it too and create a menu for each child for no reason?

**EDIT :** Is there maybe a way to use `useCallback` & `memo` to only rerender the parent and the affected child, without rerendering all the other children?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) here.

Like this:

```
const [chatLines, setChatLines] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => setChatLines([
    { id: 1, message: "Hello" },
    { id: 2, message: "Hi" },
    { id: 3, message: "Bye" },
]), []);
```

Doing so you will render chat lines only once, when the component is mounted.
But if you want to reload message on some external state changes, then you'll need to listen for this state changes in `useEffect(() => effect(), [externalState])`

Comment: It's not the point of the question, I preloaded the data in `chatLines` state to loop through it.

Comment: The problem is when I click on the `Options` button located in `ChatLine.js` component, it rerenders the parent, and I need to avoid that.